# Clojure. Update double nested value

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm kind of newbie with Clojure, all is new but pretty fun too. So I have this data:

```
 {:test {:title "Some Title"}, :questions [
   {:id 1, :full-question {:question "Foo question", :id 1, :answers [{:id 7, :question_id 1, :answer "Foobar answer"}, {:id 8, :question_id 1, :answer "Foobar answer two"}]}},
   {:id 5, :full-question {:question "Foo question", :id 5, :answers [{:id 12, :question_id 5, :answer "Foobar answer"}]}},
   {:id 9, :full-question {:question "Foo question", :id 9, :answers [{:id 14, :question_id 9, :answer "Foobar answer"}, {:id 20, :question_id 9, :answer "Foobar answer two"}]}}
 ]}
```

A "classic" **Test->Question->Answer** kind of data structure. And I have this new info:

```
 (def new-answer {:id 33, :answer "Another foobar answer", :question-id 9 })
```

I need to update the first structure to add "new-answer" into the "answers" for the **:id** number 9 in the **:questions** vector.

I tried with the **update-in** function but I don't know what to tell the correspondent **:id** in the maps inside the two vectors. I mean, I don't know how to build the "path" where I want to make the change.

Answer (score 5):

also, there is a nice library for that kind of structural editing, called [specter](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter)

your case could be solved like this:

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :refer [ALL AFTER-ELEM setval]])

(defn add-answer [data {question-id :question-id :as new-answer}]
  (setval [:questions ALL #(== question-id (:id %)) :full-question :answers AFTER-ELEM]
          new-answer data))

user> (add-answer data {:id 33, :answer "Another foobar answer", :question-id 9 })

;;=> {:test {:title "Some Title"},
;;    :questions
;;    [
;;     ;; ... all other ids
;;     {:id 9,
;;      :full-question
;;      {:question "Foo question",
;;       :id 9,
;;       :answers
;;       [{:id 14, :question_id 9, :answer "Foobar answer"}
;;        {:id 20, :question_id 9, :answer "Foobar answer two"}
;;        {:id 33, :answer "Another foobar answer", :question-id 9}]}}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea with update-in. You can first calculate the index in your questions vector, then create the path :questions, "question-index", :full-question, :answers. Then you may conj in your new answer:

```clj
(def data {...})

(defn index-by-id
  [v id]
  (first (filter #(= (:id (v %)) id) (range (count v)))))

(defn add-answer
  [answer]
  (let [q-index (index-by-id (:questions data) (:question-id answer))]
    (update-in data [:questions q-index :full-question :answers]  
           conj answer)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using clojure, you have the `update-in` function found [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) and the `assoc` found [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc). You can use the code suggested by Alex for `update-in`. `assoc` is fairly similar,

```clj
(defn change [ma a-map id]
  (assoc (:questions ma)
    (if-let [xq (first (filter int? (map-indexed (fn [idx mp] (if (= (:id mp) id) idx nil)) (:questions ma))))]
      xq
      (inc (count ma)))
            a-map))
```

You can update your map as

```clj
(change o-map n-map idx) ;;param-1 is map to change, 
                         ;;param-2 is new-answer, 
                         ;;idx is the :id to change.
```

You can also refer to `assoc-in` found [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in) which also associates a value in a nested associative structure.
Hope this helps.